# isError and factory method in PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, mdb2

Do we have a similar kind of methods in PHP PDO too???

We have a `isError()` and factory methods in Pear mdb2.

```
PEAR::isError($result)
MDB2::factory
```

Do we have a similar kind of methods in PHP PDO too???

Answer (score 0):

> Do we have a similar kind of methods in PHP PDO too?

Not quite, no.

Depending on [how you've configured PDO error handling](http://php.net/pdo.error-handling), you will either get `false` back from things that return errors, or you will get an exception.  If you've turned exception handling off, you can check [`PDO::errorCode`](http://php.net/pdo.errorcode) after you get a `false` when you would have expected something else.  This can get very messy very quickly.  Exceptions are best practice here.

PEAR's `PEAR::isError()` method came about in PHP4, when PHP did not have exceptions.  It's an ugly workaround at best.

As for the factory, there's no need here.  MDB2 was designed with a factory because each of the database types it can speak to is actually a different class.  With PDO, you define the database type as part of the constructor and always get a PDO object back, not a subclass.